# Host certain folder for public access via URL

Tags: network, hosts, docker

Hopefully I describe this in the way it can help me.

Is it possible for me to host a drive live on a website of mine, in which users anywhere, (not just my network), can access to watch/listen/play and download stuff from?
Similarly to [Snap2HTML](https://www.rlvision.com/snap2html/about.php), the application takes a snapshot of a folder's structure, and pastes it on a HTML file you can use for a website.
My desired result is just like this, but I can use it on MacOS systems, since Snap2HTML is Windows only. Being that, I did indeed test it on CrossOver, which it built the .html just fine, but I cannot redownload the files from where the .html was appointed to.

Essentially, I want to host my own file hosting service, apart from anyone else uploading anything to the drive. Anyone who visits my site, can download those files I put into the drive, that looks like an Index of that drive, similarly to [the Raspberry Pi OS' previous image UX](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/).

If anything of the similar is possible and available for Mac, please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Public access requires your router to allow incoming traffic and direct/route this to your Mac, as well as some changes on your Mac. What have you tried already, where are you stuck?

Comment: Why not host the files from GitHub or Amazon S3? Macs can download files from all sorts of network shares and web sites.

Answer (score 1):

Most webservers have built-in support for this, including [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) which is pre-installed on macOS. Functionality like that is usually disabled because it might expose sensitive files; in Apache's case, you have to enable it explicitly with [`Options +Indexes`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options). It updates live, which means you don't have to make a new snapshot if you add or remove files.

Here is an example how it could look like:

[image]

(from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60959572/4751173))